# How to get a single record from main table and details about it from another table in a one:many relation?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Jobs (Main table)

`id | name | status`

Tasks (Details table)

`id | result | job_id`

PS: Result column can have `delivered`, `undelivered` or `unknown` as a value

I want get a job by id and details about it sum by result type in a single row, something like below:

`job_id | job_name | job_status | delivered | undelivered`

I have tried the following but no success as I am not able to use job columns in this fashion. Any pointers?

```
select jobs.id, jobs.name, jobs.status, sum(case when tasks.result = 
'deliverable' then 1 end) as deliverable,
sum(case when tasks.result = 'undeliverable' then 1 end) as 
undeliverable from jobs, tasks where jobs.id = 
tasks.job_id and jobs.id = 'We3dJzS4C1wysafM';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your query has two issues:

- Improper use of table aliases (`jobs` --> `veb`)
- No `group by`

The following also fixes the archaic `join` syntax:

```
select v.id, v.name, v.status,
       sum( (t.result = 'deliverable')::int ) as deliverable,
       sum( (t.result = 'undeliverable')::int ) as undeliverable
from jobs v join
     tasks t
     on v.id = t.job_id and jobs.id = 'We3dJzS4C1wysafM'
group by v.id, v.name, v.status;
```

Comment: It was typo. So if have many columns in the jobs table, do you I need to group by each of them?

Answer (score 0):

Using common table expressions (CTEs) -

```
with deliverable_tasks as (
select t.job_id, count(*) as deliverable_count
from tasks t
where t.result='deliverable'
group by t.job_id
),
undeliverable_tasks as 
(
select t.job_id, count(*) as undeliverable_count
from tasks t
where t.result='undeliverable'
group by t.job_id
)
select
  j.id,
  j.name,
  j.status,
  dt.deliverable_count,
  ut.undeliverable_count
from jobs j
left join deliverable_tasks dt on dt.job_id=j.id
left join undeliverable_tasks ut on ut.job_id=j.id
```